# JQuery Puzzle - Getting wrong input value

Tags: jquery, input

I could describe the situation, but I think a picture would be more helpful...

[image]

How can it be, to have an element with empty value attribute and still get a value out of it?

The web is full of surprises... BAD surprises... VERY BAD ones...

Comment: Is "test6" typed into the `input` box by chance..?

Comment: Please post the code, not just a picture of  the code.

Comment: @tymeJV Ha! I have just removed the container's div style and I now see that the field gets auto filled by Chrome... I wonder why Chrome  did something like that.

Comment: @user2173353 Please can you write an answer now that you've figured out what's causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, people.

I found out what was going wrong thanks to tymeJV.

It seems that Chrome does something really stupid.

When it finds a password field, it grabs the previous input element (not carying about its name, it's DOM position, etc) and fills in the username.

(There is a password field inside the #appletDIV)

So, thank you Google!

You've just made my day...